# Drupal 7 Second Level Menu not displaying for other languages

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-7

I have a multilingual Drupal 7 site with a 2-level menu, which I set up by picking the same menu for "Primary links" and "Secondary links".

However, I have a different main menu for each language on the site. Using multilingual variables, I set both the Primary and Secondary links to be translated variables, and for each language I set both to the menu for that language.

This works fine for the default language, but for all other languages, only the top level menu items are appearing.

Any tips for making multiple 2-level menus work?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by

> by picking the same menu for "Primary links" and "Secondary links"

by two level menu you mean this stacture:

- item 1

  - item 1.1
  - item 1.2
- item 2

  - item 2.1

?

if this is the case then you should use one menu.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, that is the structure of my menu, but I have one menu for the English items, another for the German, and so on. When viewing German content, I would like the German menu to display.

Comment: use i18n for translating (menus and many other common things).

Comment: Thank you. I am using i18n, and for many sites this would be the proper way to handle translated menus. Unfortunately for this site the menu structure is different for each language, so a menu per language really is required.